# NSButton disappearing from window in 2x mode

Tags: xcode, macos, cocoa, swift2

I'm currently developing an OS X app and I just stumbled across a pretty weird bug.

This is my app's UI on a 1x resolution:
[image: @1x resolution]

and this is my app on a retina resolution:
[image: @2x resolution]

Where did that location icon in the bottom right vanish to? The icon itself is an SVG file that's configured like this: [image: Screenshot of assets.xcassets]

The `NSButton` element itself is held in place by Auto Layout constraints like it's supposed to.

Oh, also I don't have an actual device with a retina screen, I just moved the window to the second monitor that's configured to use a HiDPI resolution. This *shouldn't* be the source of the bug, but you never know.